# Hadoop cluster password-less ssh setup

Tags: hadoop, ssh

I've set up a hadoop cluster. The problem is with the ssh passwordless connection. My master node is able to connect to the slave without a password. However my slaves are asking for a password to connect to the master. When I removed the `known_hosts` file in the slave nodes, I was able to connect to the master without a password. However on reboot, it's again asking me for password.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I finally succeeded in connecting both the master and slaves via passwordless ssh. 
The following can be useful for other developers in the field:

On master:

```
ssh-keygen
ssh-copy-id user@slave
```

Then connect to slave from master: `ssh user@slave`

On slave:

```
ssh-keygen 
ssh-copy-id user@master
```

Connect to master from slave: `ssh user@master`

Enable the keys in the authorized_keys folder:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

And here we are, simple and easy!

Comment: If you have more queries, post it as a different question.

Answer (score 0):

Passwordless SSH is unidirectional. In the case of the Hadoop cluster, if you enable passwordless SSH from master to the slaves, you will still need password to authenticate and connect from any of the slaves to the master.

This is because passwordless SSH is basically public key authentication. When the master node public key is exported to the slaves, identity trust is established so that the respective user in the master node can authenticate against the slave node using its public key instead of by supplying user password.

If we want to achieve the same for SSH from a slave to the master, then each slave node public key should be exported and added to master's authorized keys file, which is consistent with what the original poster mentioned in his update.